# Flutter Webview for Ecommerce site

Tags: flutter

I am making a flutter app with webview for a ecommerce platform and would to check the following:

1. The UI should not glitch.
2. The app should use internal storage.
3. Push Notification via flutter.
4. I want to see where from which device it is accessing and placing orders from. Like If I am getting the orders from a Android, IOS or web.

Any help will be appreciated.
**PS:** I am new to flutter.

I have accessed the webview via flutter.

Comment: What is your question?  What specific issue do you need help with?

Comment: I am making an app with webview using flutter it is an ecommerce site. I want to make the look and feel just like a normal app and want device info so that I can analyze from where the user placed order from for better analytics. I also want to implement push notification via flutter with webview

Comment: "I want to..." isn't a question.  Which part of what you want to are you having difficulties with?

Comment: I am having difficulty to get device info and push notification as I am using flutter webview.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement e-commerce in Flutter...

1. The UI should not glitch.

- Generally, for the minimalistic User Interface there won't be any issue at all. But if you're trying to place too much animation and too much dynamic content, you might be having UI Glitch! In the case of complex Structure, I would suggest going for NEXT.Js.

2. The app should use internal storage.

- It's possible, There are two good ways I can suggest where you can utilize local storage. 1. [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), 2. [IsarDB](https://pub.dev/packages/isar) - Fastest Local DB for flutter

3. Push Notification via flutter.

- You may utilize Firebase Push Notification for implementing the same. There are many articles/guides to implement Firebase Notification in Flutter.

4. I want to see where from which device it is accessing and placing orders from. Like If I am getting the orders from a Android, IOS or web.

- There is a package where you can capture the device info in Flutter. Package called [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus).

let me know if you need more help!
Thanks!

Comment: I am not  making a custom app I am using webview to show the site as an app. So I need to make sure that it feels like an app. So I need to access the device info so that I can analyze how much users are using the app and I am confused for push notification with webview.

Comment: If you're rendering with webview then you may not have control to capture device info on order but you may first capture device info and then proceed to the webview (then you're unsure if the user will place an order or not). So, the capturing device must be at the website (on order), not in Flutter webview. For the push notification, if you're able to notify with API request then it may work, fire the request from WEB and continuously sniff or listen to that in Flutter.

Comment: I have found this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview which will help me be in control for custom changes. I am going through the documentation and will update my findings here.